# References about functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Good evening.

Yes, I know my title is very unimaginative, but I was not able to find a way to summarize my question.

I have a school assignment that must be written as an article, and my topic is about functional analysis. The "actual math" is pretty much done, but I am struggling to find references about two seemingly basic functional analysis facts:

- The topological vector space of test functions is separable.
- Tensor products of single-variable smooth compactly-supported real functions span a dense subspace of the topological vector space of smooth compactly-supported functions.

I already know how to prove both, but since these seem very much like known results, I would rather cite some reference. Would you happen to know of any?

Thank you.

Comment: Go to the library and flip through the (likely present) dozens of functional analysis texts on the selves?

Comment: I did try a bit of that (to no avail for this particular question), but now I can't really access the library anymore. I guess I can try out the online "equivalent", but I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: Maybe you can find a reference by searches [such as this](https://www.google.com/search?q=topological+vector+space+of+test+functions+is+separable), and then find/confirm specific page cites in any books mentioned by doing appropriate searches within books using google-books or [Hathitrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?a=page;page=advanced).

Comment: I did a “second round” today. It turns out that Treves proves the second claim, but I still cannot find a reference for the first claim.